# How to most efficiently explore the contents of a column of url query-strings

Tags: sql, url, query-string

I have a SQL table column of URL querystrings such as `"?foo=true&bar=false"`

I want to create a `SQL` query that will tell me the names of all the query parameters observed in the column, as well as all the distinct observed values of the parameters.

For example, the result would look like:

```
foo    true, false
bar    true, false
foobar 1, 2, 5, true
```

What is the most efficient algorithm to return such a result using `SQL`, possibly with and the regex capabilities afforded by the re2 library (https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Regular expression capabilities vary.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the fact that I have regex capabilities afforded in re2 library (https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)